# test servicio de angular

Tags: angular, unittest, karma-jasmine

Buen dia soy nuevo en el testing y no termino de entender la mejor forma de hacerlo aqui estamos usando Angular con Jasmine como ejemplo tengo un servicio que tiene este metodo:

```
      purchaseReward(reward: IPurchasableReward | any) {
    return this.sessionmApi.purchaseReward(reward).then(async (o) => {
      await this.idp.getUser();
      await this.getWalletRewards();
      await this.getPurchasableRewards();
      return o;
    });
  }
```

La interfase IPurchasableReward es algo asi:

```
export interface IPurchasableReward {
    getStartDate(): string | null;
    getPurchaseId(): string | null;
    getPrice(): number | null;
    getName(): string | null;
```

...
}

¿Como deberia testear este servicio? intento algo como esto, pero no es correcto creo que tengo confusion con conceptos todavia :( agradecere mucho su ayuda:

```
it('return purchace reward', (doneFn) => {
  spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'purchaseReward').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockUserOffer));
  spyOn(service['idp'], 'getUser').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockUserSessionm));

  service.purchaseReward(MockIPurchasableReward).then((data)=>{
    expect(data.id.length).toBeGreaterThan(1)
    doneFn()
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Estás usando promesas en tu servicio, ¿por qué no usas la clase de Angular HttpClient y observables? de ese modo es muy fácil testear un servicio, usando las herramientas que provee

Comment: Pero esa es precisamente la duda ¿como hacer eso que comentas? quizas sea sencillo pero yo estoy confundido para aplicarlo :(